# Accessing State that holds Array of Objects

Tags: reactjs

I apologize if this is a basic question, but I'm genuinely confused why this isn't working. I have a component that makes an API call to fetch data, and the data returns successfully, and I can do a console.log and see an array of objects as I expect.

```
.then((result) => {
                this.setState({
                    surveyData: result,
                    surveyYear: result[0].year
                });
                console.log(result); <--- This logs an array of objects as expected
                console.log(this.state.surveyData); <-- This logs an empty array
                console.log(this.state.surveyYear); <-- This logs what I expect
            })
```

When I use the return component, I get what I expect from this:

```
render(){
   return(
        <p>{this.state.surveyYear}</p> <--- this shows exactly what I'd expect
 )
}
```

But if I do the below, it should show the exact same data, but instead, I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`  Is it possible to do this way?

```
render(){
   return(
        <p>{this.state.surveyData[0].year</p> <---  I want to access the data this way instead 
 )
}
```

Comment: Post your full code in the question. You are using promises which run async and yet we cant reproduce

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pitfall in react. The issue is that updating the state is not instantaneous. This is why your data is not there yet right after the call to `setState`. Similarly in the render method you will need to guard against that data not being available yet.

If you babel your code and support the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator:

```
render(){
  return(<p>{this.state.surveyData?.[0]?.year</p>)
}
```

otherwise

```
render(){
  return(<p>{this.state.surveyData && this.state.surveyData[0] && this.state.surveyData[0].year</p>)
}
```